# Calculated column reference in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with the columns:date1,name and price. What i want to do is to add 2 columns one right having the minimum and maximum dates of the consecutive dates of the same name.

I have written the following query that explains the rule:

```
select date1,name,price
    case
    when lag(name,1) over(order by date1 ASC,name ASC)=name then lag(minDate,1) over(order by date1 ASC,name ASC)
    else date1
    end as minDate,
    case
    when lag(name,1) over(order by date1 DESC,name DESC)=name then lag(maxDate,1) over(order by date1 DESC,name DESC)
    else date1
    end as maxDate
    from MyTable order by date1 ASC,name ASC
```

My problem is that i get an "invalid context for minDate/maxDate" (SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703)
Why can't i refer to a calculated column? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining about the `lag(maxDate,1)`, because `maxDate` isn't defined in that scope; it's not a column in `MyTable`, and aliases aren't available until *after* the `SELECT` list finishes in DB2 (they become available by pushing this into a subquery, or in clauses like `HAVING`).

Incidentally, your query can be better written as the following:

```
SELECT date1, name, price,
       LAG(date1, 1, date1) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date1) AS minDate,
       LEAD(date1, 1, date1) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date1) AS maxDate
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY date1, name
```

(I've left out `ASC`, as it's the default for all ordering)

- `LEAD(...)` is the opposite function to `LAG(...)`, and looks one row *ahead*.  Using both functions this way allows the optimizer to compute just one window (what's specified in the `OVER(...)`).
- The third parameter to the windowing functions here is a default value - in the case there wasn't a next/previous row, it returns `date1` from the current row.
- `PARTITION BY` is essentially a grouping for windowing function, and takes the place of the `CASE ... WHEN ...` in your original query.  (In general, I find that such constructs reflect mentality common to imperative programming, which tends to run counter to the set-based nature of SQL.  There are usually better ways to do things)